# The html button won't let me download my excel file

Tags: php, html

I want to download excel file by using html and php.
php is working perfectly... but via html the html button doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it...
I've tried to search on Google, but I can't find the solution...
this is my html source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        phpDownloadTest
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#bt1').click(function() {
            var msg = " ";
            msg += '&sample3=' + $('#sample3').val();


            $.post("test11.php", msg).done(function() {
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open("POST", "test11.php", true);
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHttp.send(msg);

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                    }
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

and this is my php source

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sample.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    require_once 'PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $file = "PhpDownload" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";;
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue("B11", "abc")
                ->setCellValue("B12", "test")

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    echo "Download Complete!!";
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: where is you button? i don't see it in your HTML

Comment: `var msg = 'sample3=' + $('#sample3').val();` and `.done(function(data){ data.data; /* contain the output of php */ });` btw you dont need to use ajax at all... and `echo "Download Complete!!";` is part of the file

Comment: and why are you using `XMLHttpRequest()` when you already have jQuery?

Comment: and `->setCellValue("B12", "test");` <- missing semicolon